# Removing width and height attributes using JSS <Image/>

Tags: jss, experience-editor

I was wondering whether there is a way to suppress rendering the width and height attributes when using the `Image` component from `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react`? Or under the hood, it basically uses the standard Sitecore Field Renderer so not really? It ends up distorting our design.

At the moment we are using this as a workaround:

```
{isExperienceEditorActive() ? (
    <Image media={fields.Image} />
) : (
    <img src={fields.Image.value.src} alt={fields.Image.value.alt}></img>
)}
```

— but that means it still looks distorted in Experience Editor.

I suppose the other option would be to try to strip them out from DOM but I think that might cause flickering & generally seems like not a very elegant solution.

Comment: Just saw this too. It's frustrating as it's not the same way MVC rendering works. There you have the choice of leaving the width/height empty and it's not rendered. For now I'm getting round it by using CSS. width: unset; height: unset;

Comment: You can set widht={" "} and height ={" "} to remove the image height and width